# Iterate over large amount of records to generate report in Doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

What is the best approach to iterate large amount of records of a complex query with several joins in Doctrine when I want to generate a excel/pdf/whatever report?

I have trouble with memory leaks, even with ARRAY hydratator (this load the entire array in memory instead of using a buffered query!).

Comment: I won't claim that it the best approach but when I need to deal with large amounts of data then I drop down to using the Doctrine DBAL connection object and just build custom sql queries with exactly the information I need.  Bit primitive when compared to using an ORM but it's not an uncommon pattern. http://doctrine-dbal.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html

Comment: Do you have any sample code of the query as you have it so far?

Comment: @Kmeixner, is a query that I assemble with query builder depending of choices and criteria terms in a criteria form that the user submits, but in general is a query with two or three joins and I select 9 rows and then I generate excel file showing thats columns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will recommend to use the `doctrine-iterator` in combination with `php://memory` stream:

A little code example below used for an `csv` export.

```
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $iterableResult = $em->getRepository('IterableBundle:User')
                         ->createQueryBuilder('a')
                         ->getQuery()->iterate();

    $handle = fopen('php://memory', 'r+');
    $header = array('ID', 'First Name', 'Last Name', 'Email');
    fputcsv($handle, $header);

    while (false !== ($row = $iterableResult->next())) {
        fputcsv($handle, (array)$row[0]);
        $em->detach($row[0]);
    }

    rewind($handle);
    $content = stream_get_contents($handle);
    fclose($handle);
```

Comment: This solution is almost perfect. The problem is that when my query has joins to manyToOne collections, doctrine throws an error, "Iterate with fetch join in class _Document_ using association _Pages_ not allowed.", even when I group by the rowset and, for example, count the "pages".

Comment: Isn't it going to fill out the memory anyway ? Since it's going to store the whole file into `php://memory` shouldn't it be `php://output` instead ?

Comment: 'iterate' is deprecated.